# No response for ssh when Amazon EC2 running with `2/2 checks passed`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have ec2 running.

It runs continuously for 6 months and has no problem.

However today I run some Mysql sequence.

It suddenly has no response for `ssh` and `http`

I have checked status in amazon console `2/2 checks passed`

but when I ry to connect ssh it stacks.

```
ssh -v ubuntu@54.71.***.*** -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.myserver
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/whitebear/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.71.***.*** [54.71.***.***] port 22.
```

I think it looks like somehow server is freeze.

However in amazon aws console `2/2 checks passed` it can be happen??

Any suggestion appreciated . thank you very much

Comment: You probably run out of ram or disc space. Do you have CloudWatch metrics setup to monitor these?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the instance?

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)